# Remove MeshRenderer on other objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to use the current sqaure as a trigger and not dissapearing itself as another will have to.
So The square or trigger won't dissapear, just another square has to be gone when player collides with it.

Please refer the second square as "Kevin" if you want to.

[Player inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdxwx.png)
[Cube inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQrHJ.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerCubeScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public MeshRenderer MyMeshRenderer;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {

            MyMeshRenderer.enabled = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the inspector of the player and the cube?

Comment: You should be able to see the inspector of the player and the cube, just added them.

Comment: Judging from your code and inspectors the cube should disappear when the player collides with it. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What has to disappear when the player collides with the cube?

Comment: Yes it's right that my code shows that the cube should dissapear, but i want a diiferent cube to dissapear instead of the one it collides with. So when it touches that cube, then let's say a cube at the side should dissapear while the cube that triggers the dissapearing should stay.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

All you need to do is reference the Mesh Renderer of the other cube in the script.

[This should be the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBs8y.jpg)